# Is キモい a feminine expression?

Tags: slang, feminine-speech

I understand that キモい comes from 気持ち悪い and I have only heard it used by women. I am wondering if it is exclusively used by women like how ending sentences with わ or かしら is only used by women.

Comment: As istrasci writes, it is not feminine, but women might use it more often to classify and discriminate men than men do to women.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Many of my male friends in Osaka/Kansai use キモい, especially the emphatic `キモッ！`.

Comment: Good observation. In fact, using the root of an adjective is not peculiar to this particular word, but is peculiar to the Kansai dialects: `短か!`, `さむ!`,　`小さ!`, `くっさ!`. In Kansai, `きしょい` may also be used.

Comment: @sawa san Exactly~ (笑) Ah and we also say きっしょ！and ちっさ！(Do you say さぶ！in Kanto too?)

Comment: @Chocolate: If you mean さぶ as in when someone tells a lame joke, then I hear it used in Tokyo. What is きっしょ, though?

Comment: @DaveMG san, Yes but we also use さぶ just to mean 寒い. きっしょ is the same as キモッ, but I think we use きっしょ more often in Kansai.

Comment: @Chocolate I think さぶ (and even さむ) is Kansai dialect. さぶいぼ is even more obviously Kansai dialect (とりはだ in standard dialect).

Answer (score 1):

I have heard university age males in Hokkaido use きもい in a very emphatic way.